# Creating a Domain specific API

Tags: php, api, dns

I'm building an API in PHP. I want the user to only be able to use the public and private keys per domain, (as eventualy I would like to try to be able to charge for large requests). Is there any way to tell if the request is being sent from the correct domain?

regards

Comment: @Wesley van Opdorp http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103777/i-am-awarding-users-answered-even-when-they-dont-answer-the-question-just-so

Comment: You can look at the source IP of the requests, but given how easy it is to set up a proxy servers, nat gateways, etc... an IP appearing to be from the correct place means essentially nothing.

Comment: @ Layke - thank you, that is correct, I accept answers when I feel I have been answered (correctly that is)!

Comment: Are we saying that it is not possible then?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the global `$_SERVER` variable

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

You can get the domain name the request is sent from with

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']
```

Comment: That is incorrect. Straight from the docs, `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` contains _"The name of the server host under which the current script is executing. If the script is running on a virtual host, this will be the value defined for that virtual host."_

Comment: Can this be altered and changed?

Comment: Might want to take a look at this http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/13331-improved-request-getuserhost-getuserhostaddress/

Comment: The `Host`-header mentioned in the linked forum post, is bullshit. Not in the sense that it doesn't exist, but that it would have anything to do with the contents of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']`. It's sole purpose is to identify which host should receive the request, being useful for virtualhost setup. The contents of the sent header, if present, are found in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`